# How to know when SKProductDiscount is active

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, skproduct, skpaymenttransaction

We'd like to offer an Introductory Price for our app. It should be a 50% off the first year of your subscription. So we added an Introductory Price in App Store Connect but also want to time-limit it. So we'd like to enable it like let's say for one day starting in a week from now. We configured it like that on App Store Connect and it works...

Now I get my SKProduct already with an introductoryPrice set. So there already is that SKProductDiscount set (even though it's only available in the future). But when I tap it, it does not show it.

Ok... so I did another test-product. Also, set the introductoryPrice but starting now. And it will also have the SKProductDiscount set. Like expected. But when I tap it, the payment confirmation will now correctly tell me what's going on...

So my question now: On my payment dialog I'd like to tell the user up front that "Today you will get 50% off your first year". But is there any way to tell simply by looking at the SKProduct? Or will I have to time that manually? And just pray that Apple watches are set to the same time as mine?

Comment: Maybe this is a sandbox bug, `SKProductDiscount` shouldn't be available in product if you set it's availability only to next week. I will try to test the same

Comment: Would be very glad for an update... but how are we supposed to test if sandbox would behave differently :)

Comment: I tested, but I have the same issue. Sandbox subscriptions always active